# IKVM.Runtime exception in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: .net-core-2.0, ikvm

I am getting the below exception in IKVM.Runtime.dll when using IKVM in .net core 2.0 application:

```
Method not found: 'Void System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator.EmitCalli(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCode, System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention, System.Type, System.Type[])'.
```

I know that IKVM only support .Net Framework. So is there any way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The method has been removed or hidden from .NET API. It is only needed to compile stream API in Java. By rewriting your streams to Java 6 cycles you'll remove calling this method.